# Extract from string in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string;

```
String value = "(5+5) + ((5+8 + (85*4))+524)";
```

How can I split/extract logical values from this string inside parenthesis as;

```
(85*4) as one
(5+8 + one) as two
(two+524) as three
((5+5) + three) as four
...
```

Any idea? all is welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be done using some cleaver regular expression (regular expressions can not "count parenthesis"). Your best option is to use some parser generator and parse the string into an [*abstract syntax tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST for short).

Have a look at [JFlex](http://jflex.de/manual.html)/[JavaCUP](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/) for instance.

---

As it turns out, the [CUP manual](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/manual.html) actually has an example covering your situation:

```
// CUP specification for a simple expression evaluator (w/ actions)

import java_cup.runtime.*;

/* Preliminaries to set up and use the scanner.  */
init with {: scanner.init();              :};
scan with {: return scanner.next_token(); :};

/* Terminals (tokens returned by the scanner). */
terminal           SEMI, PLUS, MINUS, TIMES, DIVIDE, MOD;
terminal           UMINUS, LPAREN, RPAREN;
terminal Integer   NUMBER;

/* Non-terminals */
non terminal            expr_list, expr_part;
non terminal Integer    expr;

/* Precedences */
precedence left PLUS, MINUS;
precedence left TIMES, DIVIDE, MOD;
precedence left UMINUS;

/* The grammar */
expr_list ::= expr_list expr_part 
          | 
              expr_part;

expr_part ::= expr:e 
          {: System.out.println("= " + e); :} 
              SEMI              
          ;

expr      ::= expr:e1 PLUS expr:e2    
          {: RESULT = new Integer(e1.intValue() + e2.intValue()); :} 
          | 
              expr:e1 MINUS expr:e2    
              {: RESULT = new Integer(e1.intValue() - e2.intValue()); :} 
          | 
              expr:e1 TIMES expr:e2 
          {: RESULT = new Integer(e1.intValue() * e2.intValue()); :} 
          | 
              expr:e1 DIVIDE expr:e2 
          {: RESULT = new Integer(e1.intValue() / e2.intValue()); :} 
          | 
              expr:e1 MOD expr:e2 
          {: RESULT = new Integer(e1.intValue() % e2.intValue()); :} 
          | 
              NUMBER:n                 
          {: RESULT = n; :} 
          | 
              MINUS expr:e             
          {: RESULT = new Integer(0 - e.intValue()); :} 
          %prec UMINUS
          | 
              LPAREN expr:e RPAREN     
          {: RESULT = e; :} 
          ;
```

Comment: You won't regret it. Parser generators are really useful when it comes to doing complex parsing easily.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a parser for your expression model, for example with [JavaCC](https://javacc.dev.java.net/) and then parse the expression string into an expression tree.